# Simulate CodeIgniter form submission with cURL

Tags: php, curl

The problem is in pressing the submit button. Here is my code:

```
// init

$init = curl_init();

$url = "http://localhost/test/register/";

// set option


curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_POST, true);


$data = array(
'name' => 'mahmoud',
'email' => 'example@yahoo.com',
'password' => '134563',
'cpassword' => '134563',
'submit' => 'register'                     
);

curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

// execute

echo curl_exec($init);


// close

curl_close($init);
```

and my form....

```
<?php

echo form_open('register/validate');
echo validation_errors();

?>
<div>
    <span><label>name</label></span>
    <span><input name="name" type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span><label>email</label></span>
    <span><input name="email" type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"></span>
</div>
    <div>
        <span><label>password</label></span>
        <span><input name="password" type="password" class="textbox"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><label>cpassword</label></span>
        <span><input name="cpassword" type="password" class="textbox"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span><input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"></span>
    </div>
<?php

echo form_close();

?>
```

The code fills the inputs with values, but doesn’t seem to press submit. Why not?

I’m using the CodeIgniter framework.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP** is a server side language and cannot interact with the browser (Client).

If you just want to post the data then you could post it to the URL which handles the post data.

Comment: You can use any client side language such as `Javascript` to manipulate the browser